# How can I get children of an ancestor using spacy dependency tree in python

Tags: python, nltk, spacy

The code as follows:

```
    import spacy
    from nltk import Tree
    en_nlp = spacy.load('en')
    parsed = en_nlp(u"Photos under low lighting are poor, both front and back cameras.")
    print(u'sentence:{0}'.format(parsed.text))
    try2 = []
    print(u'parsed_sentence_children::{0}'.format([(x.text,x.pos_,x.dep_,[(x.text,x.dep_) for x in list(x.children)]) for x in parsed]))
    print("\n\n")
    for x in parsed:
        if x.pos_=="NOUN" and x.dep_=="nsubj":
            print(u'Noun and noun subject:{0}'.format(try2 =[(x.text,x.pos_,x.dep_,[(x.text,x.pos_)for x in list(x.ancestors)])])
```

The output to this is:
`[(u'Photos', u'NOUN', u'nsubj', [(u'are', u'VERB')]`

Now I wish to print `acomp` children of:
`[(u'are', u'VERB')]`
which is the ancestor of:
`[(u'Photos', u'NOUN', u'nsubj')]`

How can I do this?

Comment: so get the children's children?

Comment: Children of an ancestor are technically brothers and sisters... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can traverse the tokens:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')

text = 'Photos under low lighting are poor, both front and back cameras.'

for token in nlp(text):
    if token.dep_ == 'nsubj': # Or other forms of subjects / objects
        print(token.lemma_+"'s are:")
        for a in token.ancestors:
            if a.text == 'are': # Or however you determine your selection
                for atok in a.children:
                    if atok.dep_ == 'acomp': # Note, you should look for more than just acomp
                        print(atok.text)
```

Which outputs (in Python3):

```
photo's are:
poor
```

However, take a look at [Spacy's page on dependencies](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#dependency-parsing). There are a lot to consider. You could play around with [DisplaCy](https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/?text=Some%20of%20these%20photos%20can%20sometimes%20be%20worn&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=1&cph=1) (this link is also an example of a similar sentence, that has different dependencies).

I hope this at least helps to get you pointed in the right direction!